# Operation of time in different devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible that in different Android devices time was measured differently?

- In the database I save time in UTC
- in the reactive native application, I save the time as `new Date()`
- I COUNT THE DIFFERENCE OF TIME FOR TIMES IN THE SAME MOMENT
- RESULTS:

  - the emulator is 0 days and 0 hours (OK)
  - **the smartphone is -1 days and 23 hours (??)**

```js
let date = new Date(dateTimeDone);
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(today.getHours());

seconds = Math.floor((today - (date)) / 1000);
minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
hours = hours - (days * 24);
```

Comment: So what does `dateTimeDone` actually contain?

Comment: @misorude `dateTimeDone` is the time taken as a string from the server

Comment: "as a string" is not very precise. Is it ISO 8601 (`2018-11-05T19:09:00+09:00`)? Is it something useless like `Nov 05 2018 19:09:00`? Maybe a stringified epoch timestamp, like `1541412540`? User-entered string like `Last tuesday`? (Well, probably not this last one, I'm just saying, "as a string" can mean a lot of things :) ) Also, it can be the case that the smartphone for some reason doesn't sync with NTP, and lost track of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results

Comment: @Amadan example `2018-11-04 01:24:11.772335`

Comment: That has no timezone information. JavaScript interprets it as time wherever the execution environment is set as being (i.e. time zone of the browser). If you intended it to be UTC, you got a bug there. At least append `Z` to it: there's a big difference between `new Date("2018-11-04 01:24:11.772335")` and `new Date("2018-11-04 01:24:11.772335Z")` (unless you happen to test in Britain, I suppose).

Comment: Also, I don't think the difference is -1 days and 23 hours - it's because your difference is negative (by subtracting a later date from an earlier), and the way `Math.floor` is not symmetric around zero.

Comment: @Amadan In fact, I have different time zones set on devices. I will set the UTC time on the server

Comment: Shouldn’t set the time as UTC, could confuse the server. Just make sure thag when you send it (or use it) it is formatted as UTC, and you’re fine.